# Putting ads on Facebook, iframe

Tags: advertising, facebook, iframe

I've made a Facebook app, a small card game, which works with the Facebook iframe option.

My question is: is it allowed to put advertisements on the original page where the iframe links to, so it appears in the Facebook app? Are there any limitations? Which advertising companies allow this? (I've heard of Adsense, ain't to fond of it...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're allowed to run your own advertisements within your application on Facebook, but you have to follow their rules.

There are too many to repost here -- you should just read their Developer Policy: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Specifically, the sections on Advertising and Advertising Guidelines:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/advertisements
http://www.facebook.com/ad_guidelines.php